# A measurable implies $f^{-1}[A]$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis

All I have is intuition on this one but my gut tells me no.

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on a measurable set $E$. Is it true that $f^{-1}[A]$ is measurable if $A$ is measurable?

Comment: What topology do you have on $E$?

Comment: No, the reason being that the sigma algebra of things we deem measurable doesn't have to particularly coincide with the topology. Just pick something 'normal' for the topology and then some 'strange' sigma algebra like the empty set and the set.

Comment: The answer depends on exactly what you mean by "measurable"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterxample with the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

Let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ be the Cantor-Lebesgue function,AKA the Devil's staircase.

Define $g:[0,1] \to [0,2]$ such that $g(x)=f(x)+x$.

It is not difficult to see that $g$ is a homeomorphism.

And also $g(Cantor)$ has a positive Lebesgue measure thus exists $V \subseteq g(Cantor)$ which is non-measurable.

So $g^{-1}(V) \subseteq Cantor$ thus is measurable  as a set of measure zero
and also $g^{-1}$ is continuous.

But $(g^{-1})^{-1}[g^{-1}(V)]=V$ which is non-measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, of course not. If we consider the identity map $\newcommand{\id}{\text{id}}\id : Y\to Y$ (with $Y$ having a nontrivial topology) with the first $Y$ having the trivial $\sigma$-algebra and the second $Y$ having the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then if $\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand{\nullset}{\varnothing}\nullset\subsetneq U\subsetneq Y$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}\id\inv(U)=U$ is not measurable in the first copy of $Y$, even though it is measurable in the second copy of $Y$.

**If both spaces have the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then the answer is yes.**

*Proof:* First we need a fact about $\sigma$-algebras generated by a collection of sets, since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets.

**Lemma: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map of sets. If $S\subseteq\mathcal{P}(Y)$ generates a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$, $\cB$, then the preimage of $S$ generates the preimage of $\cB$.**

*Proof of lemma:*
Since preimages preserve intersections, unions, complements, the null set and the whole set, for any function of sets from $f:X\to Y$, and any $\sigma$-algebra $\cB$ on $Y$, the set $\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}f\inv\cB:=\set{f\inv(A) : A\in\cB}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ called the preimage of $\cB$. If $S$ generates $\cB$, then certainly $f\inv S \subseteq f\inv \cB$, so we just need to show that if $\newcommand{\cA}{\mathcal{A}}f\inv S \subseteq \cA$ for $\cA$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, then $f\inv\cB\subseteq\cA$. For this, consider $f_*\cA :=\set{ B : f\inv(B) \in \cA}$ (you can verify that this is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$). In particular, note that $S\subseteq f_*\cA$, since $f\inv S\subseteq \cA$, so since $\cB$ was generated by $S$, $\cB\subseteq f_*\cA$, which means that $f\inv\cB\subseteq \cA$. Hence $f\inv\cB$ is a subset of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $f\inv S$. Thus it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f\inv S$.

*Resuming main proof:*
Now we apply the lemma to the situation of a continuous map between topological spaces with their Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Let $f: X\to Y$ be continuous, let $\cB(X)$ and $\cB(Y)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and let $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$ be the topologies on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Then by the lemma above, $f\inv \cB(Y)$ is generated by $f\inv\tau_Y$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f\inv\tau_Y\subseteq \tau_X\subseteq\cB(X)$, so $f\inv\cB(Y)\subseteq \cB(X)$. Unravelling the definitions, this is exactly what it means for $f$ to be measurable when $X$ and $Y$ are equipped with their respective Borel $\sigma$-algebras.

> Point of caution! The key point to be careful of here is that the Lebesgue measure is strictly larger than the Borel measure on $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}\RR^n$. Hence if $f:\RR^m\to \RR^n$ is continuous, and $\cB^n$ and $\newcommand{\cL}{\mathcal{L}}\cL^n$ are the Borel and Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebras on $\RR^n$ respectively, while $f:(\RR^n,\cB^n)\to(\RR^m,\cB^m)$, and $f:(\RR^n,\cL^n)\to(\RR^m,\cB^m)$ are measurable, $f:(\RR^n,\cL^n)\to(\RR^m,\cL^m)$ and $f:(\RR^n,\cB^n)\to(\RR^m,\cL^m)$ may not be. In his answer, Marios Gretsas has provided an example of such an $f$ which is continuous but not Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable.